# DMs Guild: can stories be set in the past of the Realms?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, publishing, dms-guild

[The DMs Guild FAQ says](http://support.dmsguild.com/hc/en-us/articles/217029298-Content-and-Format-Questions):

> **Can I create and sell content for older D&D editions on DMs Guild?**
>
> Sorry, no — 5th Edition content only, please.

Does this refer to both rules and content?

**Must all Forgotten Realms stories be set in the period opened up by [Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/sc-adventurers-guide)**, the official 5th Edition update of the setting?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Yes, according to DM's Guild

Since Mearls always disavows speaking with authority, here's someone who is speaking with authority, writing today (7 June 2016):

> Hello [redacted],
>
> Thank you for contacting us regarding the DMs Guild.
>
> You can write for any timeframe of Forgotten Realms. All material produced must be 5th edition, but the history of the Faerun at large can be used.
>
> If you have further questions, let me know!
>
> All the best,
>
> --
>
> Carolyn Neumann
>
> Community Content Manager

If it ever comes up, the question I posted could be referred to as "Incident #55636"

---

For context, here's the text of the request I sent yesterday, 6 June 2016:

> Hello all-
>
> I understand from the FAQs and CCL that I should be writing material for 5e and no older *editions*. Does that mean that material must be written and set in the Realms *in the current timeline*? That is, ca. 1480-90? Or may I set my adventures in a past *time* in the Realms, as long as the *mechanics* I"m using are 5e?
>
> Many thanks,
>
> -[redacted]

Answer (score 8):

Content set in the past is fine, content in the future is... maybe ok?

Someone asked Mike Mearls a similar question on Twitter, to which he responded "Historical stuff is good for the Guild, as are regions like Maztica, etc." https://www.twitter.com/mikemearls/status/688178009203855362

Comment: Upvoted this as well - and thank you for the answer -, but in the end accepted the answer by @nitsua60 since that one cites the immediate business source itself.